# How does the paper implement NEAT without a global set tracking Innovations?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, genetic-algorithms, neat, neuroevolution

I have been reading [this](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.phd04.pdf) paper on NEAT and trying to implement the algorithm in C#. For the most part, I understand everything in the paper however, there are 2 things I don't understand that confuse me.

1. In the paper it states:

> A possible problem is that the same structural innovation will receive different innovation numbers in the same generation if it occurs by chance more than once. However, by keeping a list of the innovations that occurred in the current generation, it is possible to ensure that when the same structure arises more than once through independent mutations in the same generation, each identical mutation is assigned the same innovation number. Extensive experimentation established that resetting the list every generation as opposed to keeping a growing list of mutations throughout evolution is sufficient to prevent innovation numbers from exploding.

This implies that no global list/set is used to track innovations. If you have a global set to track them, then you wouldn't need to use a list during the evolution of the current generation because as soon as an innovation is created, it would be added to the set. This would be seen by the next evaluated Net/Genome.

From what I have read everyone uses a global list to track the innovations. This makes sense to me. I am just very confused as to how they did it in the paper considering they did extensive testing to figure out they only need a list for the evaluation of the current generation.